# custom placemark MapKit

Tags: android, mapkit

how do I use custom placemarks instead of the standard pins like this with MapKit on the android?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8uVl.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you image or icon ready to use you can easily use these code

```
if (yandexMap != null) {
        return yandexMap.getMap().getMapObjects().addPlacemark(
            point, ImageProvider.fromBitmap(icon), new IconStyle().setFlat(flatStatus)
                .setRotationType(rotationType)
                .setScale(SCALE_VALUE)
                .setAnchor(ANCHOR_VALUE));
}
```

You can set icon from resource,asset and file. 
Icon style is optional.

Point is where you want to set marker in map location.

For more information check [Yandex MapKit Documentation](https://tech.yandex.com/maps/doc/mapkit/3.x/concepts/android/mapkit/ref/com/yandex/mapkit/map/PlacemarkMapObject-docpage/)

Hope it works.